# What are some of the best practices to reduce the size of ml-related docker image?

Tags: python, docker, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm currently building a docker image that can be used to deploy a deep learning application. The image is fairly large with a size roughly 6GB. Since the deployment time is affected by the size of docker container, I wonder if there are some of best practices to reduce the image size of ml-related applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, keep the data (if any) apart from the image (in volumes for example).Also, use .dockerignore to ignore files you don't want in your image.

Now some techniques:

A first technique is to use multistage builds. For example, an image just to install dependencies and another image that starts from the first one and run the app.

A second technique is to minimize the number of image layers. Each RUN , COPY and FROM command creates a different layer. Try to combine commands in a single one using linux operators (like &&).

A third technique is to take profit of the caching in docker image builds. Run every command you can before copying the actual content into the image. For exemple, for a python app, you might install dependencies before copying the contents of the app inside the image.

Comment: Thank you for this list of advice. BTW,  "keeping the data apart from the image", if I have a model weight file in the same directory of my Dockerfile, your suggestion is to zip it to a remote location, (for instance, AWS s3), then curl it from there and unzip it to the container created by Dockerfile, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hello, my suggestion was more in the sense of creating a docker volume (check the docs: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to persist the data used by the container. Notice that, as the docs suggests, it's possible to create volume drivers, which let you store volumes on remote hosts or cloud providers.